# C# Send a template facebook message via bot framework

Tags: facebook, frameworks, bots, botframework, messenger

i'm developing a facebook bot with microsoft bot framework.
I want to send custom message  to facebook user, so i use custom channelData approach. you can find it here:
[channelData Config.](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/channels.html)
And here is my code:

```
var reply = activity.CreateReply();
reply.ChannelData = new
                    {
                        attachment = (text as SendPackage).message.attachment,
                        notification_type = "NO_PUSH"
                    };
var result = await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```

i tested it on emulator, but channelData property alway empty:

```
   {
  "type": "message",
  "timestamp": "2016-11-24T02:30:44.9047645Z",
  "from": {
    "id": "56800324",
    "name": "Bot1"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "id": "8a684db8",
    "name": "Conv1"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "2c1c7fa3",
    "name": "User1"
  },
  "text": "",
  "channelData": {},
  "replyToId": "3f223b935086422da7ed36786ab05cb9"
}
```

the result returned from ReplyToActivityAsync is null too.
Has anyone got this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I think, you should set Channel Data in Json format, not in an anonymous object. So, my suggestion is set the Channel Data like the following:

```
var channelData = "{";
var channelData += "'notification_type' : 'NO_PUSH',";
var channelData += "'attachment' : '" + text + "'";
var channelData = "}";

var reply = activity.CreateReply();
reply.ChannelData = channelData;
var result = await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```

Also, if you want to send an object which its model is complex, you can create a class model, and then using JsonConvert.Serialize serialize the object and then set it into the reply.ChannelData.

In addition, it would be better if you test your bot in a real environment using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). Therefore, you get a real message from your bot in Facebook Messenger.

Answer (score 0):

A very late answer to this, but I've had similar issues withe setting a message's ChannelData in C#.

The only method that has consistently worked for me is to use Newtonsoft.Json's JObject.FromObject:

For example:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

message.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    notification_type = "REGULAR",
    // all your other channel-specific stuff here...
});
await context.PostAsync(message);
```